# All localhost sites contain fake png files

Tags: php, wordpress, png

I've completed development of a wordpress theme for a client, but when we launched the site to an online staging server, I noticed 2 issues:

1) I have three menus created in the WP dashboard: About, Main, and Media. I've selected "Main" to be the main navigation menu, but for some reason, it's not using the menu I've selected. It's grabbing the first menu available, according to alphabetical order. In this case, it's using the About menu. If I change the name of "Main" to "AAMain", it's using the correct menu. I'm not sure how this is happening. Here's the code I'm using to register my menu:

```
register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'mobile-nav' => __( 'The Mobile Menu', 'bonestheme' )   // main nav in header
        )
    );
```

And here's the code I'm using for the menu setup:

```
// the mobile menu
function bones_mobile_nav() {
// display the wp3 menu if available
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => false, // remove nav container
    'container_class' => '', // class of container (should you choose to use it)
    'menu' => __( 'The Mobile Menu', 'bonestheme' ), // nav name
    'menu_class' => '', // adding custom nav class
    'theme_location' => '', // where it's located in the theme
    'before' => '', // before the menu
    'after' => '', // after the menu
    'link_before' => '', // before each link
    'link_after' => '', // after each link
    'depth' => 0, // limit the depth of the nav
    'fallback_cb' => 'bones_mobile_nav_fallback' // fallback function
));
} /* end bones main nav */

// this is the fallback for mobile menu
function bones_mobile_nav_fallback() {
wp_page_menu( array(
    'show_home' => true,
    'menu_class' => '', // adding custom nav class
    'include'     => '',
    'exclude'     => '',
    'echo'        => true,
    'link_before' => '', // before each link
    'link_after' => '' // after each link
) );
}
```

Lastly, this is the code used in my header.php file to pull in the menu:

```
<?php bones_mobile_nav(); ?>
```

2) The second issue is with a single page on my site. This page is using the same page template (page-about.php) as a bunch of other pages in the site, that are all loading fine. But when I try to view this page, I'm getting an error that says "No data received". "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data." "Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

**I noticed that there was a few files in my theme folder called "social.png" and social0.png". Additionally, at the bottom of my themes functions.php file, there are includes for these png files – which are actually php files, disguised as png files.**

I tried removing the png files as well as the includes in the functions.php file, but nothing seems to be working.

I've been at this for 2 days now. I've run every single scan imaginable within my WP site. The most confusing part is that everything was working perfectly until a few days ago, so I'm 99% certain my code is correct. It seems to be a bug somewhere in the site that's causing this to happen, and I can't figure out how or why this would've happened. I'm using the latest version of WP, and all of my plugins are up to date.

This seems to have affected every single site I'm running on my Mamp Pro localhost – not just this site.

Let me know if anyone has come across this, or knows what steps I can take to debug further.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your Mamp server is compromised. Try browsing to your IP address from a computer not connected to your network to verify. If so, you've got a long task of finding whatever hacks your intruder has perpetrated.

Comment: Am I trying to browse my computers IP address or the network I'm on? And what am I looking for exactly for verification? Thanks!

Comment: Go to [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) from your MAMP machine and write your IP down. Now, try to browse to http://x.x.x.x:8888 from outside your network, or just plug this into an [online port scanner](https://pentest-tools.com/discovery-probing/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap). If you get any responses, people can access your machine from the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, but this was the response given:
Nmap scan report for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [host down] 
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn